# Illegal string offset when using foreach related to SQL Statement

Tags: php, sql, joomla, foreach, k2

Why am I getting this error when trying to access any of the array keys using the following?

```
$product_cat = '22';
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery( true );
$query->select( $db->quoteName( array( 'name', 'alias', 'parent' ) ) );
$query->from( $db->quoteName( '#__k2_categories' ) );
$query->where( $db->quoteName( 'parent' )." = " .$product_cat );
$db->setQuery( $query );
$row = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($row);
foreach ($row as $value) {
    foreach($value as $result) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $result['name'] . '</a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

The following array is being returned:

> Array ( 
> [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Stimulation Chemicals [alias] => stimulation-chemicals [parent] => 22 ) 
>   [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Cementing Chemicals [alias] => cementing-chemicals [parent] => 22 ) 
>   [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Improved Oil Recovery [alias] => improved-oil-recovery [parent] => 22 )  
>   [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Drilling Fluid Additives [alias] => drilling-fluid-additives [parent] => 22 )  
>   [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Solvents and Surfactants [alias] => solvents-and-surfactants [parent] => 22 )  
>   [5] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Coil Tubing Chemicals [alias] => coil-tubing-chemicals [parent] => 22 )  
>   [6] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Production Chemicals [alias] => production-chemicals [parent] => 22 ) )

So I'm not sure what's happening, I'm simply trying to access 'name, 'alias' and 'parent' and spit them out in different places in a echoed html string. Any ideas?

Comment: On exactly which line is the error reported? You don't have an array of arrays, you have an array of `stdClass` objects. But that shouldn't break the `foreach ($value as $result)`.  You _can_ iterate over an object in that way.

Comment: Sorry Michael, the code that was breaking it was '$result['name']'. I'll update it to reflect this for future readers.

Comment: Oh I see - for some reason I was missing that in the inner loop and reading it as though you had just `$result` there (which would have worked) rather than `$result['name']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($row as $value) {
   echo '<ul>';
   echo '<li><a href="#">' . $value->name . '</a></li>';
   echo '<li><a href="#">' . $value->alias . '</a></li>';
   echo '<li><a href="#">' . $value->parent . '</a></li>';
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll mark this off as the correct answer as soon as I can. Thank you sir. I'm still a baby at this so excuse my stupidity, but in a previous project I was able to return an array with database values and access it using $whatever['name'] and so on and so forth, why doesn't that work here?

Comment: @jasenmp `$value` is an object and have the data of name and etc... so no need to iterate it again this will make slower to render the page. after second foreach `$result` variable have the value of index directly. so this (`$result['name']`) will not work. you need to give only `$result` and can access the value directly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Code Lover.